# Does Zend Framework 2.0 leave out the amazon s3 library functions that were included in 1.12?

Tags: zend-framework2

I was unable to find the equivalent of this

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html

In the 2.0 version documentation.  I also noticed that the 2.0 minimal version is 2.5MB while the 1.12 minimal version is 8.7MB and the full 1.12 version is ~30MB.

Comment: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/1941, you can download them separately https://github.com/zendframework

Comment: Thanks bernard, this makes sense since I pretty much use only 2 of the service components

Answer (score 1):

ZF2 doesn't provides a built-in library for S3 or any other AWS services by default. Zend\Service components has been removed from repository as of [July 2012](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/1941) and some of them still maintained under individual repositories.

But the good news is Amazon announced their own [AWS-SDK module for ZF2](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/2169500296594435) on March 2013. Also it has a [github link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-zf2). Currently its in very early stages and seems like a ZF2 friendly wrapper for amazon's [official PHP SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php), it's promising.

For more detailed information about this situation, [read the RFC here](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/RFC+-+Service+Components).

Answer (score 0):

I tried using something like: `use Zend\Service\Amazon\S3\S3` in my project since I use Zend Framework 2 but it didn't work!

I don't think that it's available anymore in Zend Framework 2.1. Apparently it was available in Zend Framework 2.0: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-268 but you can use `ZendServiceAmazon` which will probably do the job:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendservice.amazon.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at: http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer

"Starting with Zend Framework 2, you may now install Zend Framework or any of its individual components and their dependencies, using the dependency management tool Composer. Packages are provided by our dedicated packages repository at https://packages.zendframework.com/"